# Second order derivative, answer check

Tags: derivatives

Dear Ladies and Gentlemen,

[image: So sure this is a mistake]

I have been studying for $9$ hours already and I am going probably insane a bit, but I have a feeling our teachers assistant made a mistake when calculating the second order derivative. I strongly believe she forgot the brackets $(3x^2-x+1)^4$ and if she didn't can you please tell me how in the hell she got to that result then.

Kind Regards,
Frustrated Y1 student

Comment: It is important to avoid the use of pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers; please [edit] the question and use MathJax to include the work you have done so far to solve the problem. If you need it, here is some basic information 
about writing math on MSE:
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Ok. for future reference I will rewrite everything down using your guide. It just takes a long time, but I guess that is the trade off if you wan't your question to be understood by everyone. Thanks for the edit